# Virtualisation primary GPU

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, nvidia, amd-v

The Server is running on Proxmox VE. My goal is to use any GPU in a VM.
So I blacklisted `nvidia noveau radeon amdgpu` to ensure all GPUs are correctly accessible to assign the VFIO driver. I've added all the ids from `lspci -vnn` to `/etc/modprobe.d/vfio-pcie.conf`.

In `/etc/modules`

```
vfio
vfio_iommu_type1
vfio_pci
```

In `/etc/default/grub`

```
#--snip--
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_iommu=on"
#--snip--
```

I've regenerated my initram and grub.

The OS is installed as EFI boot.

Now here is the problem which is the cause of my confusion:
If I unplug my DVI before I boot, all my GPUs are abled to work inside any VM, if the DVI stays plugged in, the OS seems to grab the primary GPU (afterwards I'm unable to use the primary GPU in any configuration).

I've tried to add `video=efifb:off` to `/etc/default/grub` but no success.

I've tried to unbind the primary GPU on boot after the wait-quit.service but this doesn't resolved anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to add a console= statement which sends console off from vga?

Comment: Will defenitly try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive noticed an grub statement while checking the hint of
@NikitaKipriyanov 
    load_video

So i removed that and all echo statements and was abled to use all gpus for vms